# SharePoint List can't unhide hidden column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created a new list in sharepoint with 35 columns (Single line of text), then I added next additional 5 colums, but that 5 coulms automatically sets as *hidden*. I marked them as *visible* in *Show/Hide colums* menu, but when i refresh the page everything goes back to its previous state. I have no idea what to do to make them visible in my list.

Answer (score 0):

After marking your columns as visible or hidden, you need to click on "Apply" on top of the menu. After this, click on "All Items"--> "Save as" and then choose a view. If you only have one view of your list, I would name it "All Items" as suggested. Click "Save" and your changes will be visible in your list.